# Java Spring Swagger file upload

Tags: java, spring, file, swagger

I have a file upload in my java spring app. But it does not show a file upload in swagger. What can I do?

I tried this and the one in the comment below..

```java
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/add",
    method = POST,
    produces = {
        "multipart/form-data"
    }
)
public void addFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws ServerException, InsufficientDataException, ErrorResponseException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidResponseException, XmlParserException, InternalException {
        fileservice.AddAttachment(file);
}
```

Comment: Do you use Springfox or Springdoc, and which version?

Comment: I am using Springdoc 2.0.

Comment: ...and also tried 2.1.0

Comment: If you change `produces` to `consumes`, does it resolve the issue?

Comment: yes that did the job!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `@RequestMapping` annotation, replace

```
    produces = {
        "multipart/form-data"
    }
```

with

```
    consumes = {
        "multipart/form-data"
    }
```

`consumes` defines the *request* media type, whereas `produces` defines the *response* media type.